# Views on VAADIN

Tags: class, user-interface, view, navigation, vaadin

I'm very new on web applications development. I've started working on Vaadin Framework, but I don't know how to manage my application's views and the navigation. Does every view have to be separately on a class ? If so, how to instantiate them on the UI class ? I feel lost.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: have you read the book of vaadin about this?  https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html . Or the Wiki with whole section dedicated to this? https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%207 .

Answer (score 0):

A good way to begin would be to reverse engineer the quick tickets demo. This demo has a login feature, tables, charts, view navigation etc.

Demo: http://dashboard.demo.vaadin.com/

Source: https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo

**However** the vaadin website has all the information you need! https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%207 &
 https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html

I hope this helps, I didn't feel a me giving a tutorial on how to navigate between views would have been helpful when Vaadin already provides a good one.